# Reading a CSV file in Python for Data Science - Optimization

Tags: python, pandas, csv, tensorflow, data-science

I am new in python and data science and I am wondering what would be the best way to handle my csv file. 
I have a csv with 50.000 rows and 2.000 columns - 30.000Kb. 
so far my python program does not take long to read it; but I am concern about consuming so much memory and making my program slow.

Currently I am reading the file with pandas:

```
pd.read_csv( tf.gfile.Open(pathA), sep=None, skipinitialspace=True,  engine="python")
```

my questions are:

1. Should I implement optimization techniques or my csv is not that big for that?
2. what kind of techniques should I use?

   - I read that I can read in batchs like this: with open(filename, 'rb') as f ...
   - should I read in batch and keep the data in memory or
   - should I always read from the file and not keeping the data in memory

I appreciate your answers =)

Comment: The questions are a little bit too vague...it depends on your needs, the dimension of the file etc...

Comment: You might want to check the [dask framework](http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/). I'm regularly reading csv files of more than 100 mb (fewer columns though. And this works without any problem. In general: memory is there to be used, so if you don't experience any problems use that memory ;)

Answer (score 2):

If the read times are OK for you, then I wouldn't worry about premature optimisation.

There are some built-in parameters you could try within the `read_csv` method: [`chunksize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-chunking), `iterator` or `lowmemory`.

However I personally don't think that filesize is overly large. I've dealt with reading files of hundreds of thousands of rows using a 2015 MacBook.

Comment: Thank you, very useful information =) I am just interested to know more about the best practices in python and improve the overall performance of my app. The reading is not a problem (for now); but when I start to train my model then it becomes slow; but of course this could depend on many other parameters...

Comment: @DavidVela That's a very valid concern. If training your model is what makes it slow that might be a better place to start looking. If there's any general advice one can give in Python it is to use efficient underlying C-code instead of Python code. I.e. try to do as many calculations as possible inside the pandas DataFrame, or using numpys matrix/vector algebra, instead of using large loops in slow Python code.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @phil-sheard's answer. Reading in chunks using Python code will make the code more reliant on slow Python code, while `read_csv` is implemented in C-code and much quicker.

If you do want to optimize it's probably something in the settings of Pandas `read_csv`, which is already much more efficient than what you could build in surrounding Python code.

Also don't optimize if it isn't necessary, you seem to be dealing with a very small table. There's no reason to microoptimize here.

Comment: Thank you =) very nice addition and good to know that I am already using an efficient call.